# Javascript Comparing Time not working

Tags: javascript, datetime, datetime-comparison

I am trying to check if a specific ISO DateTime is before 18:00

This is the simple code:

```
   // Define the date I want to check
    var targetDate = "2015-02-04T13:30:00Z";
    // Parse the string into a date object
    var target = new Date.parse(targetDate);
    // Compare the target date againt a new date object set to 18:00:00
    if(target < new Date().setHours(18 , 0, 0)){
        console.log("BEFORE");
    } else {
        console.log("AFTER");
    }
```

even though the time in my targetDate is set to 13:30:00 the output is always AFTER.

I have search how to compare times, and from the results I found, a simple comparison as I did should work.

I would really appreciate it if someone could point out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
var targetDate = new Date("2015-02-04T13:30:00Z");
var numHours = targetDate.getHours();
if (numHours < 18) {
  console.log("BEFORE");
} else {
  console.log("AFTER");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Testing the code gives the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: function parse() { [native code] } is not a constructor
```

This is because of the "new" keyword. Removing this fixes your problem:

```js
// Define the date I want to check
var targetDate = "2015-02-04T19:30:00Z";
// Parse the string into a date object
var target = Date.parse(targetDate);
// Compare the target date againt a new date object set to 18:00:00
if (target < new Date().setHours(18, 0, 0)) {
  console.log("BEFORE");
} else {
  console.log("AFTER");
}
```

Comment: I was outputting to nodejs console and it wasn't throwing the error for some strange reason

Answer (score 1):

when you try to parse the target data, you don't have to use the `new` keyword.

[Here's an working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zq15q8om/1/);

The code:

```
 // Define the date I want to check
 var targetDate = "2015-02-04T13:30:00Z";
 // Parse the string into a date object
 var target = Date.parse(targetDate);
 // Compare the target date againt a new date object set to 18:00:00
 if (target < new Date().setHours(18, 0, 0)) {
     alert("BEFORE");
 } else {
     alert("AFTER");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can count on the ISO format and don't want to convert it to local time

you can just look at the hours substring.

```
var targetDate = "2015-02-04T13:30:00Z";

var isbefore18=targetDate.substring(11,13)-18<0;

isbefore18 /*  value: (Boolean) true */
```

Answer (score 0):

David P has the correct answer. A Date() is composed of a date part, and a time part

```
new Date().setHours(18,0,0)
```

creates a Date at 18:00 *today*, which will always be greater than 17:30 February 4, 2015, unless you have a time machine.

```
targetDate.getHours()
```

Returns the hour value of the time part, which it sounds like you are looking for.